# SharpDX:How to place SharpDX Window in Winforms Window?

Tags: sharpdx

I'm actually tryin to place SharpDX Window in Winforms Window like in the following video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-JupOxwB-k

In SharpDX this method doesn't work.Can anyone tell me how to EASILY do this ?

Comment: are you using the SharpDX/toolkit or straight SharpDX/DirectX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

don't think of it as putting a sharpDX window into a winforms window.

instead think of it as how to output SharpDX to the windows handle (sorta)

the key is in the SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChain. when creating this you will need a SwapChainDescription

I like to create mine like

```
SwapChainDescription scd = new SwapChainDescription()
{
  //set other fields
  OutputHandle = yourform.Handle,
  //set other fields
};
```

[Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle(v=vs.110).aspx)
[SwapChainDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/ns-dxgi-dxgi_swap_chain_desc?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

so when you call SwapChain.Present() it will render to the form.

this is the basic way to do it with straight SharpDX and not the toolkit stuff

**EDIT 04222019  LINKS DO NOT WORK** --- **01052022 Link fixed**

if you want to use the toolkit's GraphicsDevice you will have to set the Presenter property. in almost the same way you set the window handle in the presentation parameters.

**https://github.com/sharpdx/Toolkit/tree/master/Documentation**

also the toolkit has the RenderForm which plays nice with the Game class

**04222019**

**EDIT (DirectX Example)**

here is an example using straight SharpDX (No Toolkit). for complete examples you should refer to the github examples [HERE](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples)

As stated above all you need to do to render to a WindowsForm window is pass the Handle to the SwapChain

**visual studio 2012**

1. add the references: (all other references are default winforms project references)

[image: references to add]

2. some using statements to make things easier:

   ```
      namespace YourNameSpaceHere
      {
          using Device = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device;

          using Buffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer;

          ...the rest of the application
      }
   ```
3. the `Form` class: here we make the device, swap chain, render target , and render target view a variable of the `Form` class we are declaring

   ```
    public partial class Form1 : Form //default vs2012 declaration
    {
        Device d;                   //Direct311
        SwapChain sc;               //DXGI

        Texture2D target;           //Direct3D11
        RenderTargetView targetveiw;//DIrect3D11

        ...the rest of the form

    }
   ```
4. Initializing the Device and SwapChain: this is what works for me on my system. if you have problems than you need to research your specific implementation and hardware. DirectX (and by extension SharpDX) has methods by which you can detect what the hardware will support.

the main code Example:

```
using System;

using System.ComponentModel;//needed to overide OnClosing
//I removed useless usings
using System.Windows.Forms;

using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using SharpDX;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
using Device = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device;
using Buffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer;


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Device d;
    SwapChain sc;

    Texture2D target;
    RenderTargetView targetveiw;       

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SwapChainDescription scd = new SwapChainDescription()
        {
            BufferCount = 1,                                 //how many buffers are used for writing. it's recommended to have at least 2 buffers but this is an example
            Flags = SwapChainFlags.None,
            IsWindowed = true,                               //it's windowed
            ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(
                this.ClientSize.Width,                       //windows veiwable width
                this.ClientSize.Height,                      //windows veiwable height
                new Rational(60,1),                          //refresh rate
                Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),                      //pixel format, you should resreach this for your specific implementation

            OutputHandle = this.Handle,                      //the magic 

            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0), //the first number is how many samples to take, anything above one is multisampling.
            SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
            Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
        };

        Device.CreateWithSwapChain(
            SharpDX.Direct3D.DriverType.Hardware,//hardware if you have a graphics card otherwise you can use software
            DeviceCreationFlags.Debug,           //helps debuging don't use this for release verion
            scd,                                 //the swapchain description made above
            out d, out sc                        //our directx objects
            );

        target = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(sc, 0);
        targetveiw = new RenderTargetView(d, target);

        d.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetRenderTargets(targetveiw);

    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //dipose of all objects
        d.Dispose();
        sc.Dispose();
        target.Dispose();
        targetveiw.Dispose();
                   
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //I am rendering here for this example
        //normally I use a seperate thread to call Draw() and Present() in a loop
        d.ImmediateContext.ClearRenderTargetView(targetveiw, Color.CornflowerBlue);//Color to make it look like default XNA project output.
        sc.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

}
}
```

this is meant to get you started with using DirectX using ShaprDX in a managed environment, specifically C# on Windows. there is much much more you will need to get something real off the ground. and this is meant as the gateway to rendering on a Winforms window using SharpDX. I don't explain things like vertex/index buffers or rendering Textures/Sprites. because it is out of scope for the question.

Comment: Can you give me a full sample?I don't understand how to add this to winform and how to modify this by winform controls

Comment: @Jakub sure no problem. but the example is bare minimum as adding anything even a triangle is out of context for your question. but if you can grasp this then you can take C++/Directx examples and translate them to a c#/SharpDX implementation!

Comment: How can I resize the SharpDX window?With your sample SharpDX window is always the same size as Winform Size

Comment: @Jakub  you will have to handle the [resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize(v=vs.100).aspx) event. There, you will have to recreate the device and SwapChain with the new client width/height. then recreate everything you created with the device. Have fun!

Comment: @jakub I have a lot of code on my [github](https://github.com/RadioSpace/Quadratus/tree/master/TileEngine)

Comment: All SharpDX implementations with WPF seems to be using the D3DImage instead of creating a swapchain. Could the solution you're describing here be used with WPF as well?

Comment: @StefanAgartsson for DX11 I have hosted the winform in the  WinformElementHost. I played with the d3dimage approach but it's only for DX9. SharpDX made their own D3Dimage for DX11 but I couldn't crack that nut. MSDN for [D3Dimage and WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656710(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @StefanAgartsson I found my old project. not sure if it runs or not. it is a work in progress [mainwindow.cs](https://github.com/RadioSpace/Quadratus/blob/master/TileEngine/TileMapMaker/MainWindow.xaml.cs)